# Multiple controller types were found that match the URL in mvc app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes, attributerouting

I have a weird bug using attribute routing with the following two controllers:

```
[Route("{action=Index}")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}

[RoutePrefix("search")]
[Route("{action=Index}")]
public class SearchController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string searchTerm)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

And in the route config:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```

As you can see, the second controller should have a prefix of search

However if I go to dev.local/search?searchterm=test

I get the error

> The request has found the following matching controller types: 
>   Marshalls.WebComponents.Web.Controllers.SearchController
>   Marshalls.WebComponents.Web.Controllers.HomeController

If I remove the `[Route("{action=Index}")]` from the homecontroller, it will work fine, but then I cannot get to the homepage using `http://dev.local/`

This hasn't happened before and usually works ok so I'm wondering if anyone can spot anything obvious I have messed up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add RoutePrefix for HomeController and move Route from controller to methods/actions.

Empty string in Route and RoutePrefix attributes means that this controller or action is default.

http://dev.local/ => HomeController and Index action

http://dev.local/search?searchTerm=123 => SearchController and Index action

Please keep in mind that only one controller can have empty RoutePrefix and only one action in controller can have empty Route

```
[RoutePrefix("")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [Route("")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}

[RoutePrefix("search")]
public class SearchController : Controller
{
    [Route("")]
    public ActionResult Index(string searchTerm)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: This works but I still don't get why my version wouldn't - ie one controller had a routeprefix of search and the other was an empty one so how could that cause mvc to find the same url for both controllers?  It just seems that the act of using `[Route("")]` on the actual Index rather than `[Route("{action=Index}")] `on the controller is what seems to be the problem

Comment: @Pete Problem with your code is that you didn't define RoutePrefix for HomeController. If you decided to you RoutePrefix it should be used everywhere. You can fix it by adding [RoutePrefix("home")] to it and defining default route in route config.